# collision detection how to NOT check if player is standing on foreground tile

Tags: collision, detection

Collision detection checks if the player intersects with a piece of foreground:

```
    if (rbot2.intersects(r) && type == 8) {
        System.out.println("Collision With Foreground");
    }
```

Now as soon as you are NO longer standing on this piece of foreground I need the player to fall down. But how do I detect NOT standing on foreground ?

I tried this:

```
if (rbot2.intersects(r) && type == 8) {
  System.out.println("Collision With Foreground");
}
else
  System.out.println("No longer colliding with Foreground");
```

But the result of this is no matter where you stand, the output is ALWAYS: No longer colliding with Foreground.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rbot2.intersects(r) && type == 8) {
  System.out.println("Collision With Foreground");
}
else
  System.out.println("No longer colliding with Foreground");
```

translates to

```
if (rbot2.intersects(r) && type == 8) {
  System.out.println("Collision With Foreground");
}

if((!rbot2.intersects(r)) || (type != 8))
  System.out.println("No longer colliding with Foreground"); //probably valid always
```

You stumbled upon the "for every other possible case -  print "No longer colliding..." scenario.